# Simplification of javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to compress this code below into few lines? 
There are similar `_jq_overlay_x` and `_jq_overlay_y` statements for 8 different events. I think that will be better to compress those lines which will be better for optimization.

Thanks in advance

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#_jq_overlay_x').click( function(event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $('#_jq_overlay1').fadeOut(500); 
        });

        $('#_jq_overlay_y').click( function(event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $('#_jq_overlay1').fadeIn(500); 
        });
        $('#_jq_overlay_x').click( function(event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $('#_jq_overlay2').fadeOut(500); 
        });

        $('#_jq_overlay_y').click( function(event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $('#_jq_overlay2').fadeIn(500); 
        });
            $('#_jq_overlay_x').click( function(event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $('#_jq_overlay3').fadeOut(500); 
        });

        $('#_jq_overlay_y').click( function(event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $('#_jq_overlay3').fadeIn(500); 
        });
            $('#_jq_overlay_x').click( function(event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $('#_jq_overlay4').fadeOut(500); 
        });

        $('#_jq_overlay_y').click( function(event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $('#_jq_overlay4').fadeIn(500); 
        });
            $('#_jq_overlay_x').click( function(event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $('#_jq_overlay5').fadeOut(500); 
        });

        $('#_jq_overlay_y').click( function(event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $('#_jq_overlay5').fadeIn(500); 
        });
            $('#_jq_overlay_x').click( function(event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $('#_jq_overlay6').fadeOut(500); 
        });

        $('#_jq_overlay_y').click( function(event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $('#_jq_overlay6').fadeIn(500); 
        });
            $('#_jq_overlay_x').click( function(event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $('#_jq_overlay7').fadeOut(500); 
        });

        $('#_jq_overlay_y').click( function(event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $('#_jq_overlay7').fadeIn(500); 
        });
            $('#_jq_overlay_x').click( function(event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $('#_jq_overlay8').fadeOut(500); 
        });

        $('#_jq_overlay_y').click( function(event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $('#_jq_overlay8').fadeIn(500); 
        });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elms=[];
    for (var i=1; i<=8;i++) {
        elms.push($('#_jq_overlay'+i)[0]);
    }
    $('#_jq_overlay_x').click( function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $(elms).fadeOut(500); 
    });

    $('#_jq_overlay_y').click( function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $(elms).fadeIn(500); 
    });
});​
```

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/MgZaV/2/) to show it working!

Comment: Nope, this brokes whole preview

Comment: `$('#_jq_overlay'+i)[0]` -> `$('#_jq_overlay'+i).get(0)` ? Just a thought

Comment: @Marko - It seems to work fine for me, added a Fiddle to my answer so you can see it affecting all the elements.

Comment: @Johan - Those two do the exact same thing!

Comment: @adeneo I know, I just prefer the other one :-)

Comment: @adeneo - now your solution works even in IE. I changed <button> with    <a> element. Thanks for solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

Either use classes instead of ids or combine all of the similar ones into something like:

```
$("#object1, #object2, #object3, ...").click(function() { ... });
```

Then, just use one click and check if the object `.is(':visible')` to hide/show it.

Comment: This really doesn't sound like it answers the question at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be shortened to:

```
$('#_jq_overlay_x,#_jq_overlay_y').click( function(event) { 
   event.preventDefault();
   for (var i=1;i<9;(i=i+1)){
     $('#_jq_overlay'+i)[(/_y/i.test(this.id) ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut')](500);
   }
});
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/FdrV4/) mockup

Comment: this works  in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, but it seems doesn`t work in IE7/8

Comment: The click handler function works. In the jsfiddle mockup, the boxes are not shown in IE7/8, because IE7/8 don't know the css `rgb(a)` property. I've adjusted the example, now it also works in all IE versions.

Comment: +1 for a REALLY short solution and some cool scripting, but looking at the question I doubt the OP has any idea what is actually going on in that fiddle ?

Comment: thanks @adeneo. I've added a few comments to the jsfiddle example